# what is the first step of doing image processing with ROS?

Tags: ros, opencv, webcam, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi i am beginner with image processing and want to start that with ROS but i dont know what is the first step ? for example should i first install OpenCV? or its not important ? and may be i should install some package in my workspace ?  i have a webcam on my laptop i want to use it. please guide me if any one could.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222776/what-is-the-first-step-of-doing-image-processing-with-ros?/) by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first thing you'll need to do is get your webcam output captured by a ros node and broadcast as an image topic so that other ros nodes can use the images. Take a look at

http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam

or

http://wiki.ros.org/libuvc_camera

Both should work with a USB web cam. Then when the camera capture node is running you can use Rviz as a quick way to check the images are being published properly. Rviz is a GUI that allows you to visualize ros topics. If you click 'add' in the bottom left of the window and click on the add by topic tab you should see you camera node listed. Selecting this topic will add a new window to Rviz that should show the images from your webcam!

When this is all working you can have a look at the image subscriber tutorial tutorial here:
http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/SubscribingToImages
to get started manipulating the image data, this is where you might starting playing with OpenCV

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2015-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-18**:
[ INFO] [1450467742.148343193]: rviz version 1.11.10
[ INFO] [1450467742.148411685]: compiled against OGRE version 1.8.1 (Byatis)
[ INFO] [1450467742.676989007]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1450467742.677113146]: OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3).

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-18**:
hi thank you so much, i run usb_cam node before and could run Rviz i clicked add the result is :

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-18**:
[ INFO] [1450467742.148343193]: rviz version 1.11.10
[ INFO] [1450467742.148411685]: compiled against OGRE version 1.8.1 (Byatis)
[ INFO] [1450467742.676989007]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1450467742.677113146]: OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3).

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-18**:
i saw Rviz window with a grid i added camera but again i only have a grid i dont know how should i use the camera in rviz ?

**Comment by [hvpandya](https://answers.ros.org/users/24274/hvpandya/) on 2016-01-21**:
You have to add the image topic to Rviz.

- After you run Rviz, click on Add button on lower left corner.
- Then click 'By topic' and select the correct topic based on your camera topic name. It should look something like:

  <camera_name>/Image